# Change pixel intensity range from [0,255] to [0,1]

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

i want to change pixel range from [0,255] to [0,1] in opencv.
Is there any pre-made functions in numpy or openCV to do that? Or i need to do it handy!?

Can i use cv.normalize?

```
norm_image = cv2.normalize(img, None, alpha = 0, beta = 1, norm_type = cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype = cv2.CV_64F)
```

Comment: You divide the array with 255? You also should likely convert the type to `float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An opencv image is just a numpy array. You can thus convert the type to a `float` (or another number type that can work with fractional numbers), and then divide by 255.

So if you have an image `a`, then you can convert it with:

```
b = a.astype(float) / 255
```